# Multiple tables with sticky headers and horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want two tables side-by-side that...

1. Share the same vertical scroll
2. Have separate horizontal scrolls
3. Have sticky headers

...all within a container of flexible width and height.

Here is a codepen of my attempt: https://codepen.io/numberjak/pen/gOYGEKz

As you can see I have ticked all my requirements except for both tables having sticky headers.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll red">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Scroll 1</th>
          <th>Scroll 2</th>
          <th>Scroll 3</th>
          <th>Scroll 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll blue">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Scroll 1</th>
          <th>Scroll 2</th>
          <th>Scroll 3</th>
          <th>Scroll 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-height: 20rem;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

td, th {
  min-width: 30rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}

tr {
  height: 10rem;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That breaks the shared vertical scroll behaviour

Comment: updated pen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBWVraP you get scrollbars for both containers , they have the class scroll , so it seems what you expected ;) only removed `align-items: flex-start;` from `.container`

Answer (score 0):

Header and the body of the table are still connected, they will still have the same scroll properties. Now to let them not 'work' as a table anymore you can set the display: block. This way  and  are separated.

You can add this to your css

```
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}
table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
}
```

The scroll issue can be fixed with some javascript!

```
$(".red tbody").scroll(function() {
  $(".blue tbody").scrollTop($(".red tbody").scrollTop());
});

$(".blue tbody").scroll(function() {
  $(".red tbody").scrollTop($(".blue tbody").scrollTop() );
});
```

so the final product look like this

```js
$(".red tbody").scroll(function() {
  $(".blue tbody").scrollTop($(".red tbody").scrollTop());
});

$(".blue tbody").scroll(function() {
  $(".red tbody").scrollTop($(".blue tbody").scrollTop() );
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-height: 20rem;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

td, th {
  min-width: 30rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}

tr {
  height: 10rem;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}
table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll red">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Scroll 1</th>
          <th>Scroll 2</th>
          <th>Scroll 3</th>
          <th>Scroll 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll blue">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Scroll 1</th>
          <th>Scroll 2</th>
          <th>Scroll 3</th>
          <th>Scroll 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This gets the sticky headers working, but breaks the vertical scroll behaviour. Both tables must scroll vertically together.

Comment: @numberjak Accidentally fixed same scroll horizontal first but now i got the right behaviour